# How to configure APIs in API Gateway to accept traffic only from specified EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I changed the Authorization Type for API to AWS_IAM, then I created an user with the following policy:

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "execute-api:Invoke"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:account_id:api-id/stage/GET/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}`

And tried to access this API through postman, and it worked. But when I'm giving this user's access_key_id and secret_access_key to an EC2 instance through `aws configure` and then trying to access the API (`curl URL`), its giving me `Missing Authentication token`.

Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: First of all, you should use *roles* to assign IAM permissions to AWS resources

Comment: How do you access it through Postman? For this policy to work, you must be supplying credentials somewhere. Doing a `curl` won't supply credentials unless you authenticate as your user somehow beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

When your API Gateway is using `AWS_IAM` authentication, you must send an AWS SigV4 authenticated request to your API endpoint (just like the AWS SDKs would to the AWS APIs).

Postman has a built-in SigV4 authentication mode that makes it easy to test. However, `curl` does not. `curl` is not part of the AWS CLI, so it's not going to care what you do with `aws configure`. This is why it's failing with `curl`. Executing the command on your EC2 instance won't magically make authentication work.

In order to use `curl` to make a request, you will need to compute and calculate your own SigV4 signature parameters & headers to go along with the request.

I just found (what looks to be) a good `curl`-alternative to handle this for you:

https://github.com/okigan/awscurl

It includes an API gateway example.